# Keep getting errors with this VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I found a VBA code with a regular module and class module which both together are supposed to make a counting of repetitions in a data set. However, I keep getting errors, I fixed the small errors on the code. Anyone can check and tell me the problem here, please. thanks.

The last error I got was on this line : `V(M, 1) = Vals(I)`which is highlighted in yellow. I think the problem is in the regular module.

Class Module:

```
 Option Explicit
'Rename cQuad
Private pQ1 As Long
Private pQ2 As Long
Private pQ3 As Long
Private pQ4 As Long
Private pCnt As Long
Private pArr As Variant

Public Property Get Q1() As Long
    Q1 = pQ1
End Property
Public Property Let Q1(Value As Long)
    pQ1 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Q2() As Long
    Q2 = pQ2
End Property
Public Property Let Q2(Value As Long)
    pQ2 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Q3() As Long
    Q3 = pQ3
End Property
Public Property Let Q3(Value As Long)
    pQ3 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Q4() As Long
    Q4 = pQ4
End Property
Public Property Let Q4(Value As Long)
    pQ4 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Arr() As Variant
    Dim V(1 To 4)
        V(1) = Me.Q1
        V(2) = Me.Q2
        V(3) = Me.Q3
        V(4) = Me.Q4
    Arr = V
End Property

Public Property Get Cnt() As Long
    Cnt = pCnt
End Property
Public Property Let Cnt(Value As Long)
    pCnt = Value
End Property
```

Regular Module:

```
Sub CountForQuads()
    Dim cQ As cQuad, dQ As Dictionary, dID As Dictionary
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim V, W
    Dim sKey As String

Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 10)

With wsData
    I = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row
    J = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Last Column
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(I, J))
End With

Set dQ = New Dictionary
Set dID = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)

    'Size array for number of combos in each row
    V = Combos(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vSrc, I, 0))


    'create an object for each Quad, including each member, and the count
    For J = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
'    If V(J, 3) = 142 Then Stop
    Set cQ = New cQuad
        With cQ
            .Q1 = V(J, 1)
            .Q2 = V(J, 2)
            .Q2 = V(J, 3)
            .Q2 = V(J, 4)
            .Cnt = 1
'            .ID = V(J, 5)
            sKey = Join(.Arr, Chr(1))

            'Add one to the count if Quad already exists
            If Not dQ.Exists(sKey) Then
                dQ.Add sKey, cQ
                dID.Add sKey, V(J, 5)
            Else

                dQ(sKey).Cnt = dQ(sKey).Cnt + 1
               dID(sKey) = dID(sKey) & "," & V(J, 5)
            End If

        End With
    Next J
Next I

'Output the results
'set a threshold
Const TH As Long = 5

'Size the output array
I = 0
For Each V In dQ.Keys
    If dQ(V).Cnt >= TH Then I = I + 1
Next V
ReDim vRes(0 To I, 1 To 5)

'Headers
vRes(0, 1) = "Value 1"
vRes(0, 2) = "Value 2"
vRes(0, 3) = "Value 3"
vRes(0, 4) = "Value 4"
vRes(0, 5) = "Count"
vRes(0, 6) = "ID Number"
'Output the data
I = 0
For Each V In dQ.Keys
    Set cQ = dQ(V)
    With cQ
        If .Cnt >= TH Then
            I = I + 1
            vRes(I, 1) = .Q1
            vRes(I, 2) = .Q2
            vRes(I, 3) = .Q3
            vRes(I, 4) = .Q4
            vRes(I, 5) = .Cnt
            vRes(I, 6) = "'" & dID(V)
        End If
    End With
Next V

'Output the data
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(.Columns.Count), _
        order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False
End With
End Sub

Function Combos(Vals)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, M As Long
    Dim V

For I = 1 To UBound(Vals) - 3
    For J = I + 1 To UBound(Vals) - 2
        For K = J + 1 To UBound(Vals) - 1
            For L = K + 1 To UBound(Vals)
                M = M + 1
                V(M, 1) = Vals(I)
                V(M, 2) = Vals(J)
                V(M, 3) = Vals(K)
                V(M, 4) = Vals(L)
            Next L
        Next K
    Next J
Next I


Combos = V

End Function
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You have completely flooded people with code! If instead you trim out code that is unnecessary it will help the person answering your question. Plus the error message is also very helpful.

Comment: it says: Run time error13 : Type Mismatch.

Comment: I am sorry, Raunak, I thought giving the full code would be more useful. Yes, now I added the error code too. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of `Function Combos(Vals)` you are trying to treat `V` as an array even though you have not initialized it as such. It is just an empty variant. You need to have a `ReDim` statement for `V`. Something like this:

```
Function Combos(Vals)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, L As Long, M As Long, n As Long
    Dim V As Variant
    n = UBound(Vals)
    ReDim V(1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(n, 4), 1 To 4)

    For I = 1 To n - 3
        For J = I + 1 To n - 2
            For K = J + 1 To n - 1
                For L = K + 1 To n
                    M = M + 1
                    V(M, 1) = Vals(I)
                    V(M, 2) = Vals(J)
                    V(M, 3) = Vals(K)
                    V(M, 4) = Vals(L)
                Next L
            Next K
        Next J
    Next I
    Combos = V

End Function
```

Comment: My data now is 23 columns and 650 rows. Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge to make the change you propose really.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Now it highlights dID.Add sKey, V(J, 5) line. and  giving Run time error 9. Subcript out of range.

Comment: I fixed the bug your question actually asked about. If you have another bug, ask another question, one with a [MCVE]. It is unreasonable for you to dump a whole project on Stack Overflow and want the entire thing debugged. Your code was trying to create an array with 4 columns. Why are you then trying to access values in the 5th column?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to list a quad ( 4 columns) of data, and then in the 5th column is for the ID number.  I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't run on excel 2016.

Comment: The ID numbers won't be in the in the 5th column of V unless your code creates an array with 5 columns and puts these numbers there, something that your code doesn't even attempt to do.

Comment: There are these lines of code:  Set dID = New Dictionary and  dID(sKey) = dID(sKey) & "," & V(J, 5). I think it is there. but there is something wrong.

Comment: The problem is that your V doesn't have a 5th column, so that code makes no sense. It doesn't create a 5th column.